# Why can't I std::bit_cast the contents of a string literal?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, compiler-bug, bit-cast

While experimenting with compile-time string manipulation, I've encountered a strange phenomenon:

```cpp
#include <bit>

constexpr char str[4] = "abc";

// error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr auto x = std::bit_cast<int>("xyz");
// OK
constexpr auto y = std::bit_cast<int>(str);
```

See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dbqo7o8nc).

How come bit-casting is permitted for a `char[]` which is stored in a global variable, but not for string literals? `std::bit_cast` does not modify its source and the result is a value, so there is no potential of modifying the storage of string literals.

Comment: Compiler bug. gcc accepts it [just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/K3x1s4P1b), and the only relevant rule around string literals is for passing them as template arguments which isn't happening here.

Comment: @Barry is `constexpr auto x = cast_string<int>("xyz");` really ok? (I'm not implying, I actually don't know)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah. None of the criteria [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/bit.cast#3) are violated. And `"xyz"` itself is a constant expression.

Comment: "Reimplementing" [Ordinary multicharacter literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) as `'abc'` ^_^.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/oW7cG1fvz

Answer (score 1):

`std::bit_cast<int>("xyz")` in a constant expression is valid in C++20.
None of the criteria in [[bit.cast] p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/bit.cast#3) are violated, and neither is any precondition in the prior paragraph.

It doesn't compile in clang due to a compiler bug. See [llvm-project issue #63686](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/63686).

No one had imagined that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion could take place for arrays in ordinary C++, but LLVM's implementation of `std::bit_cast` necessitates it (see [ExprConstant.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/7505f2c92d90d559ebb95dd3e1b451a8c2546714/clang/lib/AST/ExprConstant.cpp#L4315-L4321)):

> ```cpp
> if (LVal.Designator.Entries.empty()) {
>   // Fail for now for LValue to RValue conversion of an array.
>   // (This shouldn't show up in C/C++, but it could be triggered by a
>   // weird EvaluateAsRValue call from a tool.)
>   Info.FFDiag(Conv);
>   return false;
> }
> ```